# JQuery onclick function not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to increment a score variable by one each time a div is clicked. To do this i'm using the following bit of JQuery:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var userScore = 0;
    $("circle").click(function(){
        userScore++;
        $('.results').html(userScore);
    });
});
```

With this html element:

```
<div class="circle" id="bouncer"></div>
```

Into this element:

```
<p class="results"></p>
```

However the number does not change, as far as i can tell, the code isnt running, but the js file it is in is working as a test alert does occur. What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: typo: `$("circle")` should be `$(".circle")` to select by class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're missing the dot it should be `.className`

```
$(".circle").click(function(){
    userScore++;
    $('.results').html(userScore);
});
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it, im an idiot

Comment: common mistake, also just fyi jquery has a shorthand for document ready, `$(function(){  //do stuff   });`

Comment: Honestly you are ridiculous, you're a machine. Thanks for your help.